# Error checking command line argument

Tags: c, integer

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    char * requiredi = argv[1];
    int arg1 = atoi(requiredi);


    if (arg1 < 0) {

        fprintf(stderr, "Not positive integer\n");

    }

    if (isdigit(arg1) == 0) {

        fprintf(stderr, "Not an integer\n");

    }


    return 0;

}
```

I want my argument to not be a positive integer (0 is not a positive integer for my program). I also want to make sure it only takes in an integer: it show throw an error if it sees something like `45abc`.

Comment: Not checking `argc`, are we? Who promised you there'd be any arguments at all?

Comment: Read [isdigit()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isdigit.3p.html)'s documentation. It's not for what you think it is.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you should ensure that you can pass `argv[1]` to `atoi()` before passing it, and also [isdigit()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isdigit.3p.html) is not for telling whether a number is a number or not, an `int` is always an `int` and `isdigit()` allows you to determine wither a given character is a digit character, i.e. a character of the set *[0-9]*.

To check whether your string — *the passed command line argument* — is a number or not you should use [strtol()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html) instead of `atoi()`, unlike `atoi()` with `strtol()` you can check if the input string is the representation of a valid integer or not, sample

```
int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int value;
    char *endptr;
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "too few command line arguments\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    value = strtol(argv[1], &endptr, 10);
    if (*endptr != '\0') {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid argument `%s' is not numeric\n", argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "Ok, value converted: %d\n", value);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: it fails for `3456789876543`

Comment: `./test 3456789876543`Ok, value converted: -658796737

Comment: @Heskinammo I didn't say that this was so robust that it would not fail. But if you input such a big value, then you should think whether you do need the variable to be `int` or bigger. You should understand that there is a limit for the maximum and minimum number that can be represented by an `int`, and then if you need to be out of the range of the largest possible integral type on your system, you should think about using a big numbers library.

Comment: Should probably do `long tmp;` then `tmp = strtol (argv[1], &endptr, 10);` (or use `base = 0` for auto handling of decimal, octal, hex). The `if (INT_MIN <= tmp && tmp <= INT_MAX) value = tmp;` The check on `endptr` can simply be `if (endptr == argv[1]) { /* no digits converted */ }`. Most of these are just alternative semantics.